# Non polarized capacitor uses

Tags: capacitor, electrolytic-capacitor

I am fascinated with capacitors. The ones I am most familiar with are the polarized capacitors. I know how they work and what to use them for. There is one capacitor though that I am not familiar with. It is the non polarized capacitor. How does it work? What would you use one for and what are the advantages and disadvantages of one over a polarized capacitor? Thank you very much.

Comment: I have some books that won't fit on this page on that subject.  Start here then ask a better question after understood. https://mtiinstruments.com/knowledge-center/types-of-capacitors/  then here https://studyelectrical.com/2016/12/different-types-classification-of-capacitors.html

Comment: Do you mean non-polarized electrolytics, or any capacitor that's not polarized?

Comment: Non-polarized is not one type, it is many types (ceramic, mica, polyester, polystyrene, polycarbonate, PTFE, mineral wax paper, air, vacuum, oil, PET, PPS, certain electrolytic constructions, and probably more).

Comment: You can't connect a non-polarised capacitor the wrong way round.

Comment: Non-polarized caps tend to have much lower  ESR*C =T time constants but since density is lower also limited in value. But Plastic dielectric tend to be more ideal in that they don’t have the dC/dV effects of cheap ceramic caps not the piezo effects. But stable NPO caps won’t have either of the nasty effects but then much lower density again so much smaller values better for RF.

Comment: Are you sure you're not mixing things up? What a polarized capacitor is, that is really hard to explain without first explaining a capacitor in general. Any capacitor that is not polarized is non-polarized.

Comment: Funny Thing... Look at the Snap Circuits Project #296. They tell you to use the electrolytic capacitor backwards so you can observe it leaking.

Answer (score 5):

Capacitors are just two "plates" with a dielectric gap. They are inherently "Non-Polarized" devices. The problem is that in order to get very large capacitance, you need very large "plate area" and this can take up a lot of space, even if you roll the plates into a very compact cylinder. To get higher capacitance, electrolytics use surface roughness to increase the effective surface area (usually on the anode or positive side). The dielectric is a very thin oxide layer on the surface of the rough plate, in order to make this work, the opposite electrode (typically the cathode or negative side) needs to conform to the rough surface of the anode to be in direct contact with the oxide layer. This cannot be done with a rigid metal plate. This is where the electrolyte comes in. The electrolyte is essentially a conforming "liquid" (not always) face on the cathode. Choice of electrolyte can effect the stability of the oxide layer and can make the capacitor sensitive to polarity. The polarity of capacitors that are sensitive to polarity is rarely used as an active feature in circuits. Unless you're making capacitor rockets... then polarity is an active feature.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are talking about electrolytics (or the mostly extinct tantalum) since other dielectrics (ceramic, film, paper, mica and so one) are inherently non polarized.

Polarization in this capacitors is a result of how they are actually built: the oxide forming process would be more or less inverted when subject to a negative voltage. The biggest advantage is that you can have *millifarads* (or even farads, in supercaps, a related technology) in a reasonable package. And at significant working voltage.

You were asking about non-polarized electrolytics: one major use of capacitors is AC coupling of amplifier stages and in many cases (not always) there isn't a definite bias polarity (being AC signals, to start with). And one really big use case of AC stage is the audio amplifier, which needs to go down to at least 20Hz (better make them 16Hz, and don't start even with subwoofers).

Now, the lower the frequency you need to pass the bigger (in microfarads) the capacitor you need (it makes an RC filter with the input impedance); in power amplifiers you also have large voltages so you need a capacitor with large capacitance *and* working voltage (there is also a signal quality issue, ceramics tend to distort the signal, and so on). So *this* is where the nonpolarized electrolytic shines.

There is a whole technology behind but it's more-or-less made with two polarized capacitor tied together. It cost more because it's more complex and it's somewhat of a niche market (since 99% of the times a bulk capacitor has a clearly designated bias)

Comment: Why do you say that Ta caps are mostly extinct ? I use and see them used all the time in SMPSs.

Comment: They cost too much and outside niche enviroments are replaced by ceramics and OSCONs